# azure devops - How can I use environment variables to make new variables in tasks?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I can get new string variables in tasks
But if there are environment variables in this new variable, it will fail
I need to use curl in a task to combine API and environment variables to get new variables.

```
For Simple Example
//get string variable in task it work
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: foovariable
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      FOO="FOOTEST"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FOO]$FOO"
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: echofoo
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "$(FOO)"
      //print FOOTEST

//string with variables in new variables then it will fail
variables:
  NAME: Eddy

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: foovariable
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Hello="Hi $(NAME)"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=HELLO]$HELLO"
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: echofoo
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "$(Hello)"
      //I Need it to show "Hi Eddy"
```

Please help me modify the syntax
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with do not put the environment variable called in **double quotes**. Like this:

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: foovariable
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Hello="hi "$NAME
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=HELLO]$Hello"
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: echofoo
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "$(Hello)"
```

You can see in echofoo step, it can successfully print $(Hello):

[image]